# pass a variable via add_action

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have looked at other examples on stackoverflow, however, I am not able to get this working
I am trying to pass a variable to a function via the add_action

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'addConditionalMemberDiscount');

function addConditionalMemberDiscount($cartObject )
        {
         $total_discount = ($VALUE_PASSED_TO_THIS_FUNCTION * .10);
         $cartObject->add_fee('discount', -$total_discount, false, 'zero-rate');
        }
```

How to I pass $VALUE_PASSED_TO_THIS_FUNCTION to the function via the add_action which is run conditionally in another function.

Comment: I have solved this by using global variable. however, I have read that this is not the best method. what do you experts think?

Comment: You can also use a WC_Session variable (but it requires in some cases to early initialize customer WC_Session cookie).